# Form validation not working in bootstrap select option live search

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Form validation not working in my select option live search but text box's successfully  validated

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><label>Access Level</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="access" data-live-search="true" required><option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>
            </select></div>
            </div>
    <script>
    $('form').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',

            fields: {
                access: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The First Name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },

            }

        }).on('success.form.bv', function(e,data){
            e.preventDefault(); // don't send form (demo only)
        });

    </script>
```

**Any one help me please**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error

Check demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/kkAEjq?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>

      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend>Contact Us Today!</legend>

      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input name="phone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="city" placeholder="city" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Select Basic -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
            <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
      <option value=" " >Please select your state</option>
      <option>Alabama</option>
      <option>Alaska</option>
      <option >Arizona</option>
      <option >Arkansas</option>
      <option >California</option>
      <option >Colorado</option>
      <option >Connecticut</option>
      <option >Delaware</option>
      <option >District of Columbia</option>
      <option> Florida</option>
      <option >Georgia</option>
      <option >Hawaii</option>
      <option >daho</option>
      <option >Illinois</option>
      <option >Indiana</option>
      <option >Iowa</option>
      <option> Kansas</option>
      <option >Kentucky</option>
      <option >Louisiana</option>
      <option>Maine</option>
      <option >Maryland</option>
      <option> Mass</option>
      <option >Michigan</option>
      <option >Minnesota</option>
      <option>Mississippi</option>
      <option>Missouri</option>
      <option>Montana</option>
      <option>Nebraska</option>
      <option>Nevada</option>
      <option>New Hampshire</option>
      <option>New Jersey</option>
      <option>New Mexico</option>
      <option>New York</option>
      <option>North Carolina</option>
      <option>North Dakota</option>
      <option>Ohio</option>
      <option>Oklahoma</option>
      <option>Oregon</option>
      <option>Pennsylvania</option>
      <option>Rhode Island</option>
      <option>South Carolina</option>
      <option>South Dakota</option>
      <option>Tennessee</option>
      <option>Texas</option>
      <option> Uttah</option>
      <option>Vermont</option>
      <option>Virginia</option>
      <option >Washington</option>
      <option >West Virginia</option>
      <option>Wisconsin</option>
      <option >Wyoming</option>
    </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website or domain name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
            <input name="website" placeholder="Website or domain name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- radio checks -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you have hosting?</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes" /> Yes
                                </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no" /> No
                                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text area -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Success message -->
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({

      fields: {
        first_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your first name'
            }
          }
        },
        last_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your last name'
            }
          }
        },
        email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your email address'
            },
            emailAddress: {
              message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
            }
          }
        },
        phone: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your phone number'
            },
            phone: {
              country: 'US',
              message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
            }
          }
        },
        address: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 8,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your street address'
            }
          }
        },
        city: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 4,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your city'
            }
          }
        },
        state: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select your state'
            }
          }
        },
        zip: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your zip code'
            },
            zipCode: {
              country: 'US',
              message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
            }
          }
        },
        comment: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 10,
              max: 200,
              message: 'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })

  });
```

Comment: sorry normal select option working but autocomplete(select2) not working

Comment: @HariKannan which plugin are you using for live search or autocomplete. It will be good if you replicate the problem in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: I am using bsselect [here]https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search

Comment: @HariKannan I have updated my demo link, Its working fine with the plugin